Error message on Node-Red using Twilio node
I'm running Node-Red on kubernetic, Node red was updated to the version 3.1.9. now my sms node(node-red-contrib-sms-twilio) is showing this Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/data/node_modules/node-red-contrib-sms-twilio/node_modules/twilio/lib/index.js' (line:3).
in the version 3.1.7 and 3.1.8 was working properly.
some one know how can I fix this problems?
thanks


I deleted all the node and reinstall but is having the same error.

The error implies the original npm install didn't work properly. I would get a shell in the pod and run npm install node-red-contrib-sms-twilio in the /data directory
